# read_csv() not retaining 'NUL' (C '\0') at the end of the string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am reading tsv data into dataframe using read_csv function.
My tsv file has col 'Name' (size of 6 bytes, shorter string is padded with C '\0'). When opened using notepad++, content looks like:

Name

[image]

[image]

But read_csv is reading it as:

"(ABC"

&

"(PQRST"

ignoring the NULL and ")" after null.

I have tried different options available in the forum, like encoding, converter, engine etc. nothing served the purpose.

Appreciate your time and help. Any lead would be helpful.

Comment: @Cobra The NUL character is just fine in a Python string. `'\x00'`.

Comment: Just to clarify: do you actually *want* the NUL bytes? Or do you just want to ensure that the closing parenthesis is read correctly? And: what is producing the data, is there a way of stripping out the NUL bytes at the source? By convention, NUL bytes (along with other non-printable characters) are illegal in text files, and CSV and TSV are both text formats. It's therefore entirely reasonable that Pandas doesn't support this.

Comment: @Cobra Thanks for the reply. Yes that's the last option I have in mind, as I do need to retain NUL in the output.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks for the response. I just discussed with the user &  got it clarified that stripping out NUL but keeping ")" in the output would work.

Answer (score 0):

Consider what happens here:

```
FILENAME = 'foo.txt'
STRING = '(ABC\x00\x00\x00)'

with open(FILENAME, 'wb') as file:
    file.write(STRING.encode())

with open(FILENAME) as file:
    print(file.read())
```

**Output:**

```
(ABC)
```

**Note:**

From zsh:

```
od -x foo.txt
0000000      4128    4342    0000    2900
```

**Summary:**

The binary zeroes (NUL) are in the file but are not printable. read_csv() is presumably only concerned with character sequences that are printable

Comment: Agree. But is there any way to force read_csv() to not to skip NUL ?

Comment: @Arti What would you want the column name to look like? Are you suggesting that it should be '(ABCNULNULNUL)'? If so, open the file and rewrite it (to a temporary location) after replacing all occurrences of '\x00' with 'NUL' then get read_csv() to process your temporary file

Comment: I just discussed with the user & got it clarified that stripping out NUL but keeping ")" in the output would work.

Comment: So, col. 'Name' should look like: (ABC) & (PQRST)

Comment: @Arti In that case I highly recommend the temporary file solution that I suggested previously